# Having issue downloading package from github

Tags: python, visual-studio, github, module, package

I am trying to install `pip install "web3-ethereum-defi[data]"` and I am having this error.

```
Building wheel for pyethash (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyethash (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyethash
  Building wheel for pysha3 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pysha3 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      copying sha3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      running build_ext
      building '_pysha3' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysha3
Failed to build pyethash pysha3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyethash, pysha3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I already install the "Visual Studio Build Tools 2022" and the "Desktop development with C++" in the build tool but still persisting the issue. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the correct version of Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 tools.

Find [here](https://www.phind.com/search?cache=a73bbbec-2b63-44a8-9357-13b3518d670b) a step-by-step guide on how to install the correct library."

I hope this helps!